# How to calculate the error in fsolve python like resnorm in python?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, convergence

I need to calculate the error in each iteration at solving a system of equation non-linear with `fsolve` in python, like `resnorm` of `fsolve` in MATLAB. Someone can help me if it's possible in python?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by peeking at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Use the function from the docs
def func(x):
    return [x[0] * np.cos(x[1]) - 4,
            x[1] * x[0] - x[1] - 5]

roots_dict = fsolve(func, x0 = [1,1], full_output = True)

# calculate the square sum of the residuals:
res = np.sum(roots_dict[1]['fvec'] ** 2)
```

The sum of the square of the residuals will be:

```
res
>> 2.754320890449926e-22
```